# Handeling non-stopping errors for Get-ChildItem in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception

I'm currently writing a script which should be used to get the average access/list time for a directory tree on a CIFS share. To do this I'm using the following code (as a snippet):

```
$time = Measure-Command {
    try{
        $subitems = Get-ChildItem $directory
    }catch{
        $msg = "Error accessing "+$dir+": "+$_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

That piece of code is working fine and does get me the information I want. But one issue I'm facing is that there are non stopping errors for `Get-ChildItem` which are not caught by the catch (as they are non stopping). To prevent this I could add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-ChildItem` but if I do that I won't be able to get a listing for the directory that has even one item that throws an error.

Examples of this include missing permissions and paths exceeding 260 characters (for whatever reason that is still a thing). I really would like to get that information in some way to do some further handling/reporting on it. Would anyone know how to catch those/react to those?

My research so far always suggests to use `-ErrorAcction Stop` which would "discard" any information for `$subitems` that I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to catch the error and the script to continue,I have modified your code to redirect error output and then check previous command's exit status to check whether any error occured.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$time = Measure-Command {
    try{
        $subitems = Get-ChildItem $directory 2> $outnull
        if(-not $?){

        #whatever action you want to perform
        $msg = $msg + "Error accessing "+$dir+": "+$error[0].Exception.Message
        }

    }catch{
        $msg = "Error accessing "+$dir+": "+$_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

I am concatenating $msg in the block with itself ,so that no msg will be lost by overwriting

Comment: In this case `$outnull` would seem to contain the error. It's far from a nice solution but better than none I guess. Assuming there are multiple errors you'd only get a summary for all errors rather than having information on the singular items. But I guess it will do for now. Such a shame there doesn't seem to be a better way to handle it.

Comment: @Seth for accessing error , $error[0] should be used instead of $outnull as you will get exception object ,that's why i added that $msg updation statement with $error[0].Exception.Message whenever cmdlet exit status is false